# Correcting a Regex operation in Python with re

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to substitute parts of a string to get the strings I want.

I am starting with:

```
str = '''emb_week_dim_list.append(emb_week_dim)
emb_dayofweek_dim_list.append(emb_dayofweek_dim ) 
emb_hour_dim_list.append(emb_hour_dim) 
emb_building_id_dim_list.append(emb_building_id_dim) 
emb_primary_use_dim_list.append(emb_primary_use_dim) 
emb_square_feet_dim_list.append(emb_square_feet_dim)  
emb_year_built_dim_list.append(emb_year_built_dim) 
emb_floor_count_dim_list.append(emb_floor_count_dim)
dropout_time_list.append(dropout_time) 
dense_dim_time_list.append(dense_dim_time) 
dropout_build_list.append(dropout_build) 
dense_dim_build_list.append(dense_dim_build) 
dropout_numeric_list.append(dropout_numeric) 
dense_dim_numeric_list.append(dense_dim_numeric) 
dropout_main_list.append(dropout_main) 
dense_dim_main_list.append(dense_dim_main) 
dropout_main_output_list.append(dropout_main_output) 
lr_list.append(lr)'''
```

I want to end here:

```
emb_week_dim_list = []
emb_dayofweek_dim_list = []
emb_hour_dim_list = []
emb_building_id_dim_list = []
emb_primary_use_dim_list = [] 
emb_square_feet_dim_list = [] 
emb_year_built_dim_list = []
emb_floor_count_dim_list = []
dropout_time_list = []
dense_dim_time_list = []
dropout_build_list = []
dense_dim_build_list = []
dropout_numeric_list = []
dense_dim_numeric_list = []
dropout_main_list = []
dense_dim_main_list = []
dropout_main_output_list = []
lr_list = []
```

I used the following command but it did not work.

```
import re
re.sub(r"\\n(.)\..", "=[],", str)
```

Why is this not working as I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match `.append` followed by the content between parenthesis and replace that with  `= []`

```
\.append\([^()]+\)
```

- `\.append` Match literally
- `\(` Match `(`
- `[^()]+` Match 1+ times any char except `(` or `)`
- `\)` Match `)`

For example

```
import re
re.sub(r"\.append\([^()]+\)", "=[],", str)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cqVZNy/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/tvpoJk)